# How to do case sensitive where() 'in' match in yii2 with mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

I've got a hashtags table in my mysql db, with a `string(512)` column called `tag`. I want to do a case sensitive search using Yii2's ActiveQuery, like this:

```
$expTags = ['one','two','three'];
Hashtag::find()->where(["IN","tag",$expTags])->select(["id"]);
```

In mysql, this usually means prefixing BINARY outside every value, or prefixing the column name. I tried both, I even tried "IN BINARY", nothing worked.

How to do this? I need case sensitive search, and I don't want to modify the table / column collation just to do this.

Answer (score 1):

previous answer here got it pretty close:

> ```
> $expTags = ['one','two','three'];
> Hashtag::find()->where(["BINARY IN","tag",$expTags])->select(["id"]);
> ```

`BINARY IN` (used as operator) causes a syntax error (for mysql at least)

> ```
> Hashtag::find()->where('BINARY tag in(:tag)', ['tag'=> $expTags])->select(["id"]);
> ```

and this  hits the [pdo problem of binding an array to a single param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition/920523)

this will work however:

```
Hashtag::find()->where(['BINARY(`tag`)' => $expTags])->select(["id"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$expTags = ['one','two','three'];
Hashtag::find()->where(["BINARY IN","tag",$expTags])->select(["id"]);
```

or

```
Hashtag::find()->where('BINARY tag in(:tag)', ['tag'=> $expTags])->select(["id"]);
```

Comment: I tried this approach. I'm obviously using  the above query within another, more complicated query. When I run the query, I get positional SQL parameter errors like "Parameter 3 was expected as integer, but you're sending a string". Note that I'm actually only sending two parameters in my query.